# Unable to implement when try to center horizontal edittext in linearlayout and add a textview at its left side

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` horizontal and have an `EditText` center_horizontal and everything is ok but when I try to add a `TextView` to its left side (of the EditText) the `EditText` moves to the right because both control `TextView` and `EditText` get centered. My problem is that I want that the `EditText` keeps in the center and the `TextView` to its left without moving the center position of the EditText. this is my code without the TextView

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTituloFechaAgenda"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:id="@+id/ll1agenda"
    android:background="@color/azul"

    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >



    <EditText
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/etFechaAgenda"
        style="@style/textoETFecha"
        android:background="@drawable/style_edit_text1"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:layout_width="150dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

up to there the EditText is centered ok. next I added the TextView:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTituloFechaAgenda"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:id="@+id/ll1agenda"
    android:background="@color/azul"

    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="Fecha: "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

        style="@style/textoTitulosBlanco"
        android:id="@+id/txtFechaAgenda" />

    <EditText
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/etFechaAgenda"
        style="@style/textoETFecha"
        android:background="@drawable/style_edit_text1"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:layout_width="150dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

so when I add the TextView both elements are centered and my EditText moves to the right and lose the center position. I hope you can help me. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to your problem could be, (what I understood from the question) to add a third view on right side of edittext and set it's visibility to invisible. (So that it doesn't show itself but takes the space)

Comment: yes, i am useing that trik, but must be a correct way. thanks im using your solution for now

Answer (score 0):

These do not work in Linear Layout. They work in Relative Layout

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

Use layout_weight to arrange editText and TextView

```
  <TextView
        android:text="Fecha: "
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/textoTitulosBlanco"
        android:id="@+id/txtFechaAgenda" />

    <EditText
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etFechaAgenda"
        style="@style/textoETFecha"
        android:background="@drawable/style_edit_text1"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Make center horizontal true for the edit text using Relative Layout. Try bellow code segment.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Fecha:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Edit Text" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```